# jQuery - two events firing after Twitter Bootstrap's modal close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

***My code***

I'm using a modal to show one of my views, like so:

```
# lessons/index.haml

%a{href: new_lesson_event_path(lesson), "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#myModal"}
  ="Book now"
```

When this button is clicked, a modal is rendered on top of the current view the user is on.

My modal is initially defined on the application view level:

```
# layouts/application.haml

#myModal.modal.fade{:tabindex => "-1", style:'margin-top:50px'}
  .modal-dialog.modal-lg
    .modal-content
```

And the view is rendered inside `modal-content` like so:

```
# events/new.haml

.modal-header
  %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
    %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} &times;
  %h4.modal-title
    ="Sign up for #{@lesson.team_name}"
.modal-body
  # my view content
.modal-footer
  %button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} Close
```

---

***My issue***

This all works great, but whenever I close the modal, it seems that the JavaScript in my original `lessons/index` view has another set of event listeners added on top.

---

***Current debugging status***

I have a `slideToggle()` event on `lessons/index` that gets fired twice whenever I close the modal.  When I open and close the modal multiple times, it seems to only fire twice... when the modal is initially defined on the application level.

I've tried multiple different lines that do something similar to `$(this).off()` and `$(this).removeEventListener(stuff)` whenever `hidden.bs.modal` is fired, to clear the script that seems to be thrown on top every time... but none work.

```
# this event is fired when the modal is closed... Only fires once every time.
$('#myModal').on 'hidden.bs.modal', (e) ->
  console.log('hidden event fired' + JSON.stringify(e, undefined, '\t'))
  $(this).off()
  $("#myModal").off()
```

If I move the outside modal contents from `application.haml` to `lessons/index.haml`, the event listeners seem to stack on top of each other, and the amount of times the `slideToggle()` event fires seems to increment as I open and close the modal more and more times (interior modal contents remain in the modal view `events/new`).

All I can conclude from all of this is that event listeners are being stacked, and I'm not sure how to unstack them.  Any suggestions? Are there more tests I can do?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use [event.stopPropagation() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp).

That would prevent the parent elements from firing their events after the modal close was invoked. It might worth a try.

Comment: I tried using `e.stopPropogation()` after `$(".more-info-btn").on "click", (e) ->`, but it still fires twice.  `e.isPropogationStopped()` returns `true`.  Are you suggesting `stopPropogation()` on the `$('#myModal').on 'hidden.bs.modal', (e) ->` trigger?

Comment: Yes, on the close event of the modal, I understand the problem is coming from there. `...but whenever I close the modal...`